# Display Multiple webviews

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to display 2 WebViews in an Android application simultaneously. I would like to know if this is possible as I have not come across any application that does that. If there is a way can someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
        make you xml like below

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/web1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/web2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


        write you activity below code


                WebView webView1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
                WebView webView2 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web2);

                WebSettings settings1 = webView1.getSettings();
                WebSettings settings2 = webView2.getSettings();
                settings1.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                settings2.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView1.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
                webView1.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

                webView1.loadUrl("www.google.co.in");
                webView2.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```